# Socket.io not working in react native when I did live node js code into server but working fine in localhost

Tags: node.js, react-native, socket.io

Socket.io not working in react native when I did live nodejs code into the server but working fine in localhost with IP but not with name localhost also I am using shared hosting can't use IP instead domain name

```
    //Client Side Code---
    import socketIo from "socket.io-client"; let socket; 
    
    //working fine in localhost with IP
    const ENDPOINT = "http://192.168.1.2:3000/"; 
    
   //not working in localhost 
    const ENDPOINT = "http://localhost:3000.com/";
    
    not working in live server 
    const ENDPOINT = "http://domainnaeme.com/";
    
    useEffect(() => {
    
    socket = socketIo(ENDPOINT, { transports: ['websocket'] } );
    
    socket.on('connect', () => { console.log('Connected');
    
    }) },[]);
```

Comment: Hey friend, in `react-native` apps that you are trying to develop, the best way of connecting the app with the server running on the localhost using the `IP`

Comment: Just some tips for the feature use of the person that has asked the question